# Notepad and removing all instances between backslashes

Tags: notepad

Sample format.

```
 \Sesame Street\elmo\
```

I want to get rid of everything including the backslashes but the text for each is different.

Sample format.

\Sesame Street\ \

Again, I want to get rid of everything including the backslashes but the text for each is different.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you copy it from notepad into a text editor that supports regular expressions, like notepad2 or notepad++ or jgsoft editpad pro

Answer (score 1):

Plain original Notepad does not support any kind of wildcards or regular expressions, just literal matching. So the only effective option is "use a different editor".

It may be helpful to ask "why are you using notepad?" when deciding which other editor to use.